# Magento - Get a Collection from current viewed product Attribute

Tags: php, magento, attributes

I'm trying to return a collection of products, in the product view page, made from an attribute taken from the *current viewed product*.

In other words, let's say I sell CDs, and I'm viewing a Ray Charles CD.
In this very product page, I'd like to show others products that have the value 'Ray Charles', in the 'artist' attribute. Except this value has to be dynamically pulled from the current viewed product's 'artist' value.

I've just learned to do this:

```
<?php 

    $model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $collection = $model->getCollection();;
    $collection->addFieldToFilter('artist', '81');
    $collection->load();

?>
```

Which can return a collection of products based on the artist attribute with an ID of '81'. But this is static.

How can I tell my collection to check for the 'artist' value of the *current viewed product* and use it to filter its results?

product/view.phtml

Thanks much for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Product pages register the viewed product already so you only need to retrieve it:

```
$currentProduct = Mage::registry('current_product');
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('artist', $currentProduct->getArtist());
```

Comment: Thanks so much! It worked! You just made my day.

Actually I have a question related to the code I left you above, especially here:
`$collection->addFieldToFilter('artist', '81');`
I notice this filter didn't work if I use the actual value label 'Ray Charles', but only work with the ID of that value.
`$collection->addFieldToFilter('artist', 'Ray Charles');` wouldn't work for some reason. Any ideas about this?

Comment: Both "Dropdown" and "Multiple Select" type of attributes store a numeric index rather than the text value. This means the database has less to store and can search for a number faster than text. When you try to filter by the text it is not comparing like to like so nothing is returned.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for your feedback and time so far, you've been amazing.